# Reshape pandas dataframe with calculation linked to 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas

From this dataframe, I want to calculate different stats at the team level

```
data = [['20-10-2020', 'PSG', 'Man U', 1, 2], ['20-10-2020', 'Leipzig','Istanbul',2,0], ['27-10-2020', 'Istanbul','PSG',0,2], ['27-10-2020', 'Man U','Leipzig',5,0]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Date', 'Home', 'Away', 'HG', 'AG']) 
print(df)

         Date      Home      Away  HG  AG
0  20-10-2020       PSG     Man U   1   2
1  20-10-2020   Leipzig  Istanbul   2   0
2  27-10-2020  Istanbul       PSG   0   2
3  27-10-2020     Man U   Leipzig   5   0
```

For instance, for each team, I calculate the number of points and goals from the previous game. The naive implementation creates two dataframes, one for the home teams and one for the away teams and concatenate them. I tried using `melt` but I did not find the syntax to achieve the dataframe I wanted.

```
df_home = df.reset_index(level=0)
columns = {
    "Date": 'date',
    "Home": "team",
    "Away": "opponent",
    'HG': 'team_goals',
    'AG': 'opponent_goals',
}
df_home = df_home.rename(columns=columns)
df_home['site'] = 'H'

df_away = df.reset_index(level=0)
columns = {
    "Date": 'date',
    "Home": "opponent",
    "Away": "team",
    'HG': 'opponent_goals',
    'AG': 'team_goals',
}
df_away = df_away.rename(columns=columns)
df_away['site'] = 'A'

df_team = pd.concat([df_home, df_away], ignore_index=True).sort_values(['date'])
df_team['team'] = df_team['team'].astype('category')
df_team['opponent'] = df_team['opponent'].astype('category')
print(df_team)

   index        date      team  opponent  team_goals  opponent_goals site
0      0  20-10-2020       PSG     Man U           1               2    H
1      1  20-10-2020   Leipzig  Istanbul           2               0    H
4      0  20-10-2020     Man U       PSG           2               1    A
5      1  20-10-2020  Istanbul   Leipzig           0               2    A
2      2  27-10-2020  Istanbul       PSG           0               2    H
3      3  27-10-2020     Man U   Leipzig           5               0    H
6      2  27-10-2020       PSG  Istanbul           2               0    A
7      3  27-10-2020   Leipzig     Man U           0               5    A
```

With this dataframe I can calculate the stats based on the `team` column

```
conditions = [df_team['team_goals'] > df_team['opponent_goals'], df_team['team_goals'] == df_team['opponent_goals']]
choices = [3, 1]
df_team['pts'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)
f = lambda x: x.shift(1).rolling(1).sum()
df_team['form_l1_before'] = df_team.groupby(['team'])['pts'].apply(f)
df_team['goal_l1_before'] = df_team.groupby(['team'])['team_goals'].apply(f)
print(df_team)

   index        date      team  opponent  team_goals  opponent_goals site  \
0      0  20-10-2020       PSG     Man U           1               2    H   
1      1  20-10-2020   Leipzig  Istanbul           2               0    H   
4      0  20-10-2020     Man U       PSG           2               1    A   
5      1  20-10-2020  Istanbul   Leipzig           0               2    A   
2      2  27-10-2020  Istanbul       PSG           0               2    H   
3      3  27-10-2020     Man U   Leipzig           5               0    H   
6      2  27-10-2020       PSG  Istanbul           2               0    A   
7      3  27-10-2020   Leipzig     Man U           0               5    A   

   pts  form_l1_before  goal_l1_before  
0    0             NaN             NaN  
1    3             NaN             NaN  
4    3             NaN             NaN  
5    0             NaN             NaN  
2    0             0.0             0.0  
3    3             3.0             2.0  
6    3             0.0             1.0  
7    0             3.0             2.0
```

The problem is that I want to convert that dataframe back with one row per game (identified by the `index` column) and each stats has its own columns

```
# Ex second game for Istanbul and PSG with stats from the previous game
expected_data = [['27-10-2020', 'Istanbul','PSG',0,2,0,0,0,1]]
df_target = pd.DataFrame(expected_data, columns = ['date', 'Home', 'Away', 'HG', 'AG', 'Home_form_l1_before', 'Home_goal_l1_before', 'Away_form_l1_before', 'Away_goal_l1_before'])
print(df_target)
         date      Home Away  HG  AG  Home_form_l1_before  \
0  27-10-2020  Istanbul  PSG   0   2                    0   

   Home_goal_l1_before  Away_form_l1_before  Away_goal_l1_before  
0                    0                    0                    1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach. We can reshape `df_team` using the `site` flag, then take the point of view `H` (home) for all information except the ones you need for both home and away (`ha_fields`). The latter are kept for both sites, and joined to the home data.

```py
ha_fields = ["form_l1_before", "goal_l1_before"]

unstacked_team = df_team.set_index(["index", "site", "date"]).unstack("site")

ha_df = unstacked_team[ha_fields]
ha_df.columns = ha_df.columns.to_flat_index().map(lambda t: "_".join([t[1], t[0]]))

df_final = (
    unstacked_team.swaplevel(axis=1)["H"]
    .drop(ha_fields, axis=1)
    .join(ha_df)
    .reset_index("date")
)

print(df_final)
```

```
             date      team  opponent  team_goals  opponent_goals  pts  \
index                                                                    
0      20-10-2020       PSG     Man U           1               2    0   
1      20-10-2020   Leipzig  Istanbul           2               0    3   
2      27-10-2020  Istanbul       PSG           0               2    0   
3      27-10-2020     Man U   Leipzig           5               0    3   

       A_form_l1_before  H_form_l1_before  A_goal_l1_before  H_goal_l1_before  
index                                                                          
0                   NaN               NaN               NaN               NaN  
1                   NaN               NaN               NaN               NaN  
2                   0.0               0.0               1.0               0.0  
3                   3.0               3.0               2.0               2.0
```